# Use image icons to filter library view web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, filter, image-display

We are on SharePoint O365.  I have created a wiki page on a classic page setup.  On that page I have placed several .gif images and the library view web part.  What I'd like to do is filter the library view web part simply by clicking on one of the images. I know I can set up the image to take me to a new page/specific url, but I don't want to be taken to a new page.  After clicking an image the library view web part would refresh to show just items linked to the image selected.  Is this possible?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So after ALOT of digging I came across a post that suggested using Promoted Links web part. On the page I placed the PLWP and the Library View web part.  Using the filters provided I filtered the list, copied the url of that view, then used that url as the link for a specific image in my PLWP.

Works like a charm!

Link to the post:  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/427655fc-d1b0-4c9d-b57b-707a224f20e3/promoted-links-to-display-different-views-of-library-in-web-part?forum=sharepointgeneral

Comment: Glad you got it solved. Another angle would be to include a URL variable filter web part (think they're called Query Filter) on the page, and have the image URLs point to the same page with a unique URL variable for each image. For example, image A would point to myPage.aspx?$myFilter=apples and image B would point to myPage.aspx?$myFilter=bananas ...